# Supressing R output

Tags: r

I need to supress output from an R function -- I have found a hack, but it *feels* like the wrong way to do it.

Right now, i'm combining `invisible` and `capture.output` -- which is effective, but it feels very hacky to chain together two similar tools to supress the output.

The function's output I need to supress is `blpConnect` from the `Rbbg` [package](http://findata.org/rbloomberg/).

```
require(Rbbg)
invisible(capture.output(conn <- blpConnect()))
```

For those that are interested, `invisible` returns the following:

```
> conn <- invisible(blpConnect())
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) 
rJava Version 0.9-4 
Rbbg Version 0.4-155 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.4.8.1\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.4.8.1
```

Same output for `invisible(conn <- blpConnect())`

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Enlightening commentary on the appropriate use of the two commands, and when and why they work as they do would be valuable.

Comment: Just `invisible` is insufficient?

Comment: @thelatemail -- nope, doesn't do it. I added output from just `invisible` to the qn.

Comment: what if you wrap it the other way `invisible(conn <- blpConnect())?`

Comment: Same output is returned.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure then, thanks for clarifying though - have a +1 for doing so.

Comment: There's an argument `verbose` - set that to `FALSE`?

Comment: The `invisible` function just suppresses the printing of the return value when used interactively - it does nothing to stop printing of things output by `print` or `cat` etc from within functions. Compare: `> sqrt(2)` with `> invisible(sqrt(2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conn <- blpConnect(verbose=FALSE)`